# Moment startOf() function chaining

Tags: angular, momentjs

I am trying to chain together the `startOf()` function to get the first day of the month in a date picker component.  It is "working" in one app, but not in another.  The app it is working in uses Angular v2.4.6, and the non-working app is using Angular v2.0.0-rc.4.  They are both using Moment v2.17.1.  The just copied and pasted the date picker component from the 2.4.6 project to the rc.4 project.  In Webstorm, there are no errors in the 2.4.6 date picker file, but the following code snippet is giving `Unresolved function or method startOf()` on the second `startOf()` call in the rc.4 project.

```
public _last(date) {
    return Moment(date).startOf('month').startOf('day');
}
```

If I separate the second `startOf()` call into its own function, then no errors are being displayed in the date picker component.

```
public _firstMonth(date) {
    return Moment(date).startOf('month');
}

public _first(date: Moment) {
    let momentDate = this._firstMonth(date);
    return Moment(momentDate).startOf('day');
}
```

That doesn't make any sense to me since `Moment(date).startOf('month')` returns an object with type `Moment` in both cases as seen in the Moment interface.

```
interface Moment {
    ...
    startOf(unitOfTime: unitOfTime.StartOf): Moment;
    ..
}
```

I don't know if this is just a bug in the IDE or has something to do with the difference in Angular 2 versions.